# Testable code contains sending broadcast - Android Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, koin, mockk

The function to be tested contains triggering broadcast as follows,I do not want to test the broadcast trigger mechanism, need to test code above this broadcast trigger code, which is related to in-app memory. After storing data into the in-app memory, need to send broadcast to update some views with the in-app memory stored data.

```
sendBroadcast(
            Intent(application,
                Receiver::class.java
            ).apply {
                action = "some action"
            })
```

Upon executing the unit test getting **java.lang.RuntimeException: Method setAction in android.content.Intent not mocked**.

If used default values for android components,

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

getting , **io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for:sendBroadcast(null)**.